# Acer Nitro 5 Linux - HDMI output for external monitor

Tags: 18.04, hdmi, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-geforce

I have an Acer Nitro 5 AN515-52 with i7 8750H, 8GB RAM, Nvidia 1050TI and 1TB HDD with 16GB IntelOptane.

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.2. I had to first boot up with nomodeset in grub (before quite splash) otherwise it freezes after login screen. I have installed latest nvidia drivers (390 although it shows 430 but as open source) after which it boots up fine. But, when I see the details in settings, it's still showing Intel Graphics. I typed nvidia-smi in the terminal which gave this output:

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

I am having trouble getting the hdmi output to my external monitor. xrandr doesn't show any HDMI connection as well. HDMI works well while using Ubuntu USB live stick and in windows too so I'm sure that the issue is not with HDMI port.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I have solved the issue by upgrading to nvidia driver to 430 and prime select. (For some reason it was not showing as available earlier). Although there was a boot up problem showing again (with no icons but screen and cursor) and after repeatedly failing nomodeset in the grub it somehow worked in the next boot without nomodeset.

Answer (score 0):

The new drivers in Ubuntu can detect the new monitor.

But after a reboot, the external monitor is not shown.

```
before shutdown
sudo prime-select intel
start
login
sudo prime-select nvidia
Logout
login
```

settings are restored and the external monitor is detected

don't forget to run
sudo prime-select intel
before shutdown

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying for so long to get external monitor working without the prime-select switching.

I'm using ubuntu 22.04, I was in a situation where I had unclaimed VGA,
and fucked up mokutils, resulting in me getting locked out of the bios.

If you locked yourself out of the bios like I did,
then I recommend https://www.biosbug.com/acer-10-digit/

Then remove all nvidia drivers, after that you can follow the article above.
The key point is to install the linux-oem kernal, it was all the extra kernal mods for using builtin-screen and external monitor working together and I can now finally use redshift and brightness settings.

I finally was able to after following this post:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/finally-i-was-able-to-configure-the-nvidia-driver-and-everything-works-properly-on-my-acer-nitro-5-with-linux-mint-20-3-cinnamon/201890

> 1° - Upgrade or do a fresh Install of Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon
> 2° - If you have performed a fresh install, after starting the system for the first time, install all available updates in the Update Manager, and restart the system.
> 3° - Now, edit the grub file (/etc/default/grub) and change the parameter “quiet splash” to “quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0”
> 4° - Then, save the changes to the file and run the command: sudo update-grub
> 5° - Install Kernel 5.14.0-1020-oem using this command: sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04d
> 6° - Reboot your system using the Kernel 5.14.0-1020-oem
> 7° - Open the Driver Manager and install the following driver: nvidia-driver-495 (Version 495.46-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 / NVIDIA driver metapackage)
> 8° - Reboot your system again
>
> After the reboot, the NVIDIA card will be used by default with all its functions configured, including the HDMI port.